# Обьясните, почему меняется иконка D:\ диска?

Tags: windows, диск

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Раньше оно ещё было и с иконкой диска, а сейчас поменялось на чёрт что

Comment: я думаю так получилось, потому что вы вручную настраивали внешний вид иконки для диска, а потом либо переместили, либо удалили указанный вами файл. Сбросьте внешний вид на значение по умолчанию (в свойствах).

Comment: ух ты, семерка, 1000 лет не видел

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кто-то перекопировал какой-то CD\DVD в корень диска `D:\` и туда затесался `autorun.inf` со строкой `icon=icon.ico`. Сам файл с иконкой конечно же удалён.

Так что один и вариантов решения проблемы я вижу в следующей строке:

```
del D:\autorun.inf ; shutdown -r -t 0
```